# How to concatenate String respecting RTL/LTR

Tags: swift, string, internationalization

When concatenating strings, how can I make Swift respect locale right-to-left language settings?

```
import Foundation

var leftString = "1"
let rightString = "2"

let concatString1 = "\(leftString)\(rightString)" // 12
let concatString2 = leftString + rightString // 12
let concatString3 = String(format: "%@%@", leftString, rightString) // 12
let concatString4 = [leftString, rightString].joined(separator: "") // 12
let concatString5 = leftString.appending(rightString) // 12
```

How could I get `21` for RTL languages and `12` for LTR languages, depending on the locale setting of the users device?

Is the only way specifying a format like `"%2$@%1$@"` in a strings file?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function or extension for it. I have used a function in my previous project. You can check if that work for you.

```
func getDirectionalString(leftString : String, rightString: String) -> String
{
    if(UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.rightToLeft)
    {
        //RTL
        return "\(rightString)\(leftString)"
    }
    return "\(leftString)\(rightString)"
}
```